# adding legend on GeoServer

Tags: maps, gis, legend, geoserver

[image]

I am new to GeoServer and I am trying to add a legend on an existing map. I am not sure where to add the legend XML file?

In the GeoServer user manual, they briefly talk about legend but it is not very clear: http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/advanced/wmsdecoration.html
I think the legend XML file should be added in the web map services page (WMS). But I tried to search for the key word like legend or something on the page but I cannot find it. Am I on the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are referring to WMS overlay decorations.

In the link http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/advanced/wmsdecoration.html that you included in the post, it gives the instructions needed to mimic the screenshot you've referenced.

> To use decorations in a GetMap request, the administrator must first
>   configure a decoration layout. These layouts are stored in a
>   subdirectory called `layouts` in the `GeoServer Data Directory` as XML
>   files, one file per layout. Each layout file must have the extension
>   .xml. **Once a layout foo.xml is defined, users can request it by adding
>   &format_options=layout:foo to the request parameters.**

In essence, you:

1. create a descriptor file like what is offered in your post
2. Copy this file to the `layouts` folder that exists in the Data Directory on
   the Geoserver (the specific path varies on the installation)
3. craft requests for the wms layer with querystring parameters to instruct
   the server that you want to see the layer with the specified
   overlay. i.e. `&format_options=layout:foo` to the request parameters.

This embeds the overlay onto the layer itself.  This is in contrast with Jose's answer which involves an additional HTTP request (which could be referenced in a `<img href=""/>` tag).

In either case, the legend component can be influenced by also applying a style in the request for the layer.  These are commonly coded with SLD.  For information on that is available [here](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-introduction.html)

== Edit 01 == 
For Reference, the path to the data directory can be found here:
[image]
This is the path on the server where geoserver is installed where the data directory resides.  The [Structure of Data Directory](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/datadirectory/data-dir-structure.html) link has some detail on what is in this folder and the purpose of each item.

Comment: Thanks Jason! I was having trouble finding the "layout" folder... Is it in the WMS page? There's no "layout" keyword there tho..,

Comment: That folder isn't available through the web gui.  Its in the server filesystem.  Look for the places where the sample layers are.  The web gui will tell you where that path is if you navigate to the status page.  On the 2.6 server I have its http://host:portgeoserver/web/?wicket:bookmarkablePage=:org.geoserver.web.admin.StatusPage

Comment: Where's the server filesystem? I looked for the sample layers but I don't see server filesystem... sry the link you sent me shows blank when I open it

Comment: I've edited my answer.  I hope that helps.  You have to log into and edit files on the server that hosts geoserver.  The actions you need to take edit the layouts directory cannot be done through the geoserver web ui.

Comment: After following the above advice, each tile returned from geoserver contains a legend. This adds a lot of clutter to the map since 12 tile requests are required to cover the entire map. How do you configure the layout to only get one legend for the map?

Comment: @Nathan Reese : Do you have an example you can share somewhere?
 What version of geoserver?  What version of the WMS spec are you using?

Comment: I am using geoserver 2.10.1. The client is requesting GetMap with WMS version 1.1.1. The client is using leaflet 0.7.7 to generate the WMS requests. How would geoserver know that 12 separate http requests are getting stitched into a single map?

Comment: @Nathan Reese: A great point.  I believe this overlay decoration technique will work well only with the `Single Tile` option in the layer preview.  In leaflet, you'd set the the vendor parameter `tiled` to false in the querystring as outlined here: http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/vendor.html  to properly show the overlay.  If disabling tiling isn't desirable and having a geoserver created legend is important -- consider the use of GetLegendGraphic to get an image and position it yourself in your application.

Answer (score 3):

I think the request you are looking for is GetLegendGraphic. With this request you are requesting Geoserver to return an image that corresponds to the default SLD of a layer or to a SLD specified in the request.

This is a sample request that you can find in the Geoserver documentation:

http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&VERSION=1.0.0&FORMAT=image/png&WIDTH=20&HEIGHT=20&LAYER=topp:states&legend_options=fontName:Times%20New%20Roman;fontAntiAliasing:true;fontColor:0x000033;fontSize:14;bgColor:0xFFFFEE;dpi:180

For more information and all the parameters that you can specify in the request:
http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/get_legend_graphic/legendgraphic.html

If you are looking for a request to get the SLD file content instead of an image to handle it in the application you will need to do a GetStyle request.

I hope that helps.